# Value entered int the first column cell of Data Grid should be populated in other columns of the same cell using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can i design an application with below requirements. Since i am rookie in WPF , i am investigating a way to do it . [write up is enough]

WPF application with following requirements.

- A row that would sit as the first row in a WPF GridView.
- The row will sit below the grid column headers and above the data rows and be 
  located within the grid itself.
- When any cell in the first row receives data, that data is populated down the 
  column for the same cell within the grid
- After the cell is updated down the column, the cell contents [in the first 
  row] are cleared
- handle sorting, filtering, paging, column re-ordering, column resizing, etc

  - allow for custom CellTemplate and EditCellTemplate

Conditions :

be applied to other grids in the future

No code behind

adhere to good OOPs, WPF design principle, be testable ,be implemented within 
 an MVVM framework.

Comment: Sounds like you're just asking for someone to do your work for you? post some code and people will gladly help and point you in the right direction.

Comment: You could use the headertemplate to give you textboxes or whatever so the top row is actually part of the header. Bind the values to some separate instance of your row viewmodel. Then pass some logic into your row viewmodel class so it sets the properties to your defaults when instantiated. You'd want that behaviour to be switchable of course.

Comment: @RandomCoder no code available now. I thinking of designing an architect now.

Comment: @Andy is this headertemplate comes with WPF ready made or we have to use any 3rd party ?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think of would be to use the header template of each column.

I suggest this because it'll fit with the way the datagrid works. It's already a separate row, you can bind to a different object and so on.

You would define this.

That would look something like the following markup ( this is just air code ).

```
<DataGridTextColumn …..
    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Text="Some Header Text"/>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeDefaultForThisColumn}"
```

Binding the textbox to another object will be a bit fiddly since a column is an abstract and not in the visual tree. You will be able to find questions about binding that if you google though.

When the user clicks that last row in the datagrid to add, the constructor of the type bound will be used. Hence my advice to inject your object containing the header edited data or some sort of a factory method sets properties.

You may of course want to be able to switch off setting any properties of your row viewmodel so it's not a problem when newing existing ones up.